# Produce lnk file on GNU/Linux to transfer to windows

Tags: linux, windows, lnk

I'll explain my goal first to avoid "XY Problem" misunderstandings.
I want to be able to produce a file (on Linux) that, when downloaded to a Windows machine and double clicked, will open a (ms office, but it shouldn't matter IIUC) file with a known path (on the local windows machine) preset by the server.

It seems what I'm trying to do is possible if I include the path of the file I want to open (and neither of the other details regarding the volume it's stored in etc) in the lnk file.
I first checked the lnk file format specs trying to generate the file in a python script but that's not my piece of cake (I never wrote code to handle binary files before). Besides, there are many features of that format that I want to ditch, but I still have to grok their flags/fields/lenghts/termination etc.

Then I stumbled upon the winedump utility and some .lnk files created by WINE in my ~/.wine folder.
There must be some function in the WINE codebase that is able to generate a lnk file, but I couldn't find it.
Where is it?
Is it in the form of a command like win's mklink?
If not (and I guess it's a function somewhere if it's not) can you point it to me so that I can write a wrapper command?

Or is there any library that can write lnk files and run on GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 8):

These are untested by me but I did find 2 tools on [this site](http://www.mamachine.org/mslink/index.en.html) which does describe the 2 tools as follows:

> This application allow you to create Windows Shortcut files (extension .LNK) without needing a Windows OS.

The first app is a [C app](http://www.mamachine.org/mslink/mslink_v1.0.tar.gz), the second is a Bash shell script. Here's the Shell script, [`mslink.sh`](http://www.mamachine.org/mslink/mslink.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

#############################################################################################
# mslink.sh v1.0
#############################################################################################
# Ce script permet de créer un Raccourci Windows (Fichier .LNK)
# Script créé en se basant sur la doc 
#   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx
#############################################################################################

OPTIONS=$(getopt -q -n ${0} -o hl:o:p -l help,lnk-target:,output-file:,printer-link -- "$@")

eval set -- ${OPTIONS}

IS_PRINTER_LNK=0
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help) HELP=1 ;;
    -l|--lnk-target) LNK_TARGET="$2" ; shift ;;
    -o|--output-file) OUTPUT_FILE="$2" ; shift ;;
    -p|--printer-link) IS_PRINTER_LNK=1 ;;
    --)        shift ; break ;;
    *)         echo "Option inconnue : $1" ; exit 1 ;;
  esac
  shift
done

if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Option(s) inconnue(s) : $@"
  exit 1
fi

[ ${#LNK_TARGET} -eq 0 ] || [ ${#OUTPUT_FILE} -eq 0 ] && echo "
Usage :
 ${0} -l cible_du_fichier_lnk -o mon_fichier.lnk [-p]

Options :
 -l, --lnk-target               Précise la cible du raccourci
 -o, --output-file              Enregistre le raccourci dans un fichier
 -p, --printer-link             Génère un raccourci de type imprimante réseau
" && exit 1

#############################################################################################
# Fonctions
#############################################################################################

function ascii2hex() {
    echo $(echo -n ${1} | hexdump -v -e '/1 " x%02x"'|sed s/\ /\\\\/g)
}

function gen_IDLIST() {
        ITEM_SIZE=$(printf '%04x' $((${#1}/4+2)))
        echo '\x'${ITEM_SIZE:2:2}'\x'${ITEM_SIZE:0:2}${1}
}

function convert_CLSID_to_DATA() {
    echo -n ${1:6:2}${1:4:2}${1:2:2}${1:0:2}${1:11:2}${1:9:2}${1:16:2}${1:14:2}${1:19:4}${1:24:12}|sed s/"\([A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]\)"/\\\\x\\1/g
}

#############################################################################################
# Variables issues de la documentation officielle de Microsoft
#############################################################################################

HeaderSize='\x4c\x00\x00\x00'                           # HeaderSize
LinkCLSID=$(convert_CLSID_to_DATA "00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046")   # LinkCLSID
LinkFlags='\x01\x01\x00\x00'                            # HasLinkTargetIDList ForceNoLinkInfo 

FileAttributes_Directory='\x10\x00\x00\x00'                 # FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY
FileAttributes_File='\x20\x00\x00\x00'                      # FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE

CreationTime='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
AccessTime='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
WriteTime='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

FileSize='\x00\x00\x00\x00'
IconIndex='\x00\x00\x00\x00'
ShowCommand='\x01\x00\x00\x00'                          # SW_SHOWNORMAL
Hotkey='\x00\x00'                               # No Hotkey
Reserved='\x00\x00'                             # Valeur non modifiable
Reserved2='\x00\x00\x00\x00'                            # Valeur non modifiable
Reserved3='\x00\x00\x00\x00'                            # Valeur non modifiable
TerminalID='\x00\x00'                               # Valeur non modifiable

CLSID_Computer="20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d"               # Poste de travail
CLSID_Network="208d2c60-3aea-1069-a2d7-08002b30309d"                # Favoris réseau

#############################################################################################
# Constantes trouvées à partir de l'analyse de fichiers lnk
#############################################################################################

PREFIX_LOCAL_ROOT='\x2f'                            # Disque local
PREFIX_FOLDER='\x31\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'        # Dossier de fichiers
PREFIX_FILE='\x32\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'          # Fichier
PREFIX_NETWORK_ROOT='\xc3\x01\x81'                      # Racine de serveur de fichiers réseau
PREFIX_NETWORK_PRINTER='\xc3\x02\xc1'                       # Imprimante réseau

END_OF_STRING='\x00'

#############################################################################################

# On retire l'anti-slash final s'il y en a un
LNK_TARGET=${LNK_TARGET%\\}

# On sépare le chemin racine du lien de la cible finale
# On distingue aussi si le lien est de type local ou réseau
# On définie la valeur Item_Data suivant le cas d'un lien réseau ou local

IS_ROOT_LNK=0
IS_NETWORK_LNK=0

if [[ ${LNK_TARGET} == \\\\* ]]; then
    IS_NETWORK_LNK=1
    PREFIX_ROOT=${PREFIX_NETWORK_ROOT}
    Item_Data='\x1f\x58'$(convert_CLSID_to_DATA ${CLSID_Network})

        TARGET_ROOT=${LNK_TARGET%\\*}
        if [[ ${LNK_TARGET} == \\\\*\\* ]]; then
                TARGET_LEAF=${LNK_TARGET##*\\}
        fi
        if [ ${TARGET_ROOT} == \\ ]; then
                TARGET_ROOT=${LNK_TARGET}
        fi
else
    PREFIX_ROOT=${PREFIX_LOCAL_ROOT}
    Item_Data='\x1f\x50'$(convert_CLSID_to_DATA ${CLSID_Computer})

    TARGET_ROOT=${LNK_TARGET%%\\*}
        if [[ ${LNK_TARGET} == *\\* ]]; then
        TARGET_LEAF=${LNK_TARGET#*\\}
        fi
    [[ ! ${TARGET_ROOT} == *\\ ]] && TARGET_ROOT=${TARGET_ROOT}'\'
fi

if [ ${IS_PRINTER_LNK} -eq 1 ]; then
    PREFIX_ROOT=${PREFIX_NETWORK_PRINTER}
    TARGET_ROOT=${LNK_TARGET}
    IS_ROOT_LNK=1
fi

[ ${#TARGET_LEAF} -eq 0 ] && IS_ROOT_LNK=1

#############################################################################################

# On sélectionne le préfixe qui sera utilisé pour afficher l'icône du raccourci

if [[ ${TARGET_LEAF} == *.??? ]]; then
    PREFIX_OF_TARGET=${PREFIX_FILE}
    TYPE_TARGET="fichier"
    FileAttributes=${FileAttributes_File}
else
    PREFIX_OF_TARGET=${PREFIX_FOLDER}
    TYPE_TARGET="dossier"
    FileAttributes=${FileAttributes_Directory}
fi

# On convertit les valeurs des cibles en binaire
TARGET_ROOT=$(ascii2hex ${TARGET_ROOT})
TARGET_ROOT=${TARGET_ROOT}$(for i in `seq 1 21`;do echo -n '\x00';done) # Nécessaire à partir de Vista et supérieur sinon le lien est considéré comme vide (je n'ai trouvé nul part d'informations à ce sujet)

TARGET_LEAF=$(ascii2hex ${TARGET_LEAF})

# On crée l'IDLIST qui représente le cœur du fichier LNK

if [ ${IS_ROOT_LNK} -eq 1 ];then
    IDLIST_ITEMS=$(gen_IDLIST ${Item_Data})$(gen_IDLIST ${PREFIX_ROOT}${TARGET_ROOT}${END_OF_STRING})
else
    IDLIST_ITEMS=$(gen_IDLIST ${Item_Data})$(gen_IDLIST ${PREFIX_ROOT}${TARGET_ROOT}${END_OF_STRING})$(gen_IDLIST ${PREFIX_OF_TARGET}${TARGET_LEAF}${END_OF_STRING})
fi

IDLIST=$(gen_IDLIST ${IDLIST_ITEMS})

#############################################################################################

if [ ${IS_NETWORK_LNK} -eq 1 ]; then
    TYPE_LNK="réseau"
    if [ ${IS_PRINTER_LNK} -eq 1 ]; then
        TYPE_TARGET="imprimante"
    fi
else
    TYPE_LNK="local"
fi

echo "Création d'un raccourci de type \""${TYPE_TARGET}" "${TYPE_LNK}"\" avec pour cible "${LNK_TARGET} 1>&2

echo -ne ${HeaderSize}${LinkCLSID}${LinkFlags}${FileAttributes}${CreationTime}${AccessTime}${WriteTime}${FileSize}${IconIndex}${ShowCommand}${Hotkey}${Reserved}${Reserved2}${Reserved3}${IDLIST}${TerminalID} > "${OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

Comment: I'll report that both these tools seem to work as advertised (at least in my limited testing).  There's no difference in functionality between the C and shell script version as they both work the same way.  The C program might be faster if you need to create thousands of .lnk's quickly, but the shell script version is perfectly adequate.    Despite having French comments and usage, is still readily understandable even if you can't read French.   In both cases, **be sure to use backslashes for the target path and enclose in single quotes.**  as in ` mklink -l '\\server\dir\file'  -o my.lnk`